# How do I make NVIDIA my main graphics card to use?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have an NVIDIA GPU and latest drivers installed. However, when I run `dxdiag` and go to the Display tab, it says my device name is Intel HD Graphics 3000. I should be using the NVIDIA card though.

*However*, I read somewhere that I can set the NVIDIA to take over when I play games (Dota 2). How can I check this? Could that be why the Intel card is listed?

**Update:** that other question's answer didn't fix my problem. I went into the nvidia control panel and changed the global setting to apply the nvidia processor, but when I run `dxdiag` I still see the Intel Graphics card listed.

Comment: You have to change the setting in the BIOS.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/525041/29943

Comment: it is a duplicate. but to clarify there is no change in bios required. nvidia control center will detect your game and run it with nvidia gpu. even if it doesn't you can easily define your own application profile from nvidia control center interface (or choose run this with graphics adapter.. option from right click menu)

Comment: @BenVoigt unfortunately, that didn't seem to change what `dxdiag` thinks.  It still says I'm using the intel card.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: Did you set (in Optimus configuration) `dxdiag.exe` as one of the applications that uses the dGPU?

Comment: @BenVoigt how do I do that? I assumed that `dxdiag` just checks whatever is being used at the moment.

Comment: You would have to look into the NVIDIA Control Panel and the Application specific setups. That decides which card is automatically used for an application. Alternatively the answer to this question could be viable.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the icon that launches the game and then click "run with graphics processor" then select Nvidia

Comment: By including some more information this would be a great improvement for this answer.